# Vertex Buffer Objects in PyOpenGL - vertex, index and colour

Tags: macos, opengl, numpy, vbo, pyopengl

OSX 10.8.3, Python, PyOpenGL.

I'm trying to put together a basic terrain-drawing function in PyOpenGL using VBOs. Having a couple of problems I don't know how to resolve, mostly because I don't fully understand the way VBOs work. This is a basic test sandbox I started when I had too much difficulty changing my project over to VBOs, so it's sloppy in places (see: frame counter).

- I've hardcoded a basic 3x3 terrain array and corresponding index array, but it seems to be only drawing two of three rows (it does the y=0 row and y=0.5 but not y=2.0). I'm not entirely comfortable with numpy, so that might be the cause.
- The contents of the colour array have only erratic bearing on the final colours: assigning numpy.zeros() to the array produces a black screen, assigning numpy.ones() produces green and purple stripes rather than the white surface I'm expecting. Was initially using random colours but that didn't do anything different from ones(). I don't really understand how OpenGL is supposed to determine that this is a color VBO rather than anything else.
- The triangle-drawing algorithm will be problematic, when I get to it - I don't know how best to draw multiple rows without using GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART, which isn't available in GLUT (I'd rather only change to GLFW or similar as a last resort). Right now, I'm not too concerned about it. Drawing in strips like this isn't quite what I want: http:// www.matrix44.net/cms/notes/opengl-3d-graphics/understanding-gl_triangle_strip (sorry, don't have 10 reputation)

How it currently looks, when rotating: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LIJK.png

Have been using http://www.mbsoftworks.sk/index.php?page=tutorials&series=1&tutorial=8 as my most successful guide.

I'd really appreciate some guidance with this - no single resource I've found on the web has explained it all, and this isn't exactly a complex topic.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
from math import sin, cos, tan, radians, sqrt
from numpy import *
from random import random

hWindow = 0

frameno = 0
sr2 = sqrt(0.75)

def InitGL( nWidth, nHeight ):
    glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
    glClearDepth( 1.0 )
    glDepthFunc( GL_LESS )
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST )
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH )

    print str(glGetString( GL_VERSION ))

    global terrain_vbo, index_vbo, color_vbo

    # these two will produce a working (huge) triangle
    #terrain_array = array([[ 0,0,0 ], [ 9,0,0 ], [ 0,9,0 ], [ 0,0,9 ]], dtype=float32)
    #index_array = array([ 0,1, 0,2, 0,3, 2,3, 2,1],dtype=ubyte)


    terrain_array = array([ [[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,2]], 
                            [[1,0.5,0], [1,0.5,1], [1,0.5,2]], 
                            [[2,2,0], [2,2,1], [2,2,2]] ], dtype=float32)


    index_array = array([   0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5,
                            8, 4, 7, 3, 6 ], dtype=ubyte )

    color_array = zeros( (9, 3) )

    for i in range(9):
        color_array[i] += (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    '''
    color_array[0] = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    color_array[1] = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
    color_array[2] = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    color_array[3] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
    color_array[4] = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
    '''
    #for i in range(len(terrain_array)):
        #index_array[i][0] = i
    for i in range(len(terrain_array)):
        print terrain_array[i]

    terrain_vbo = vbo.VBO(terrain_array)
    #index_vbo = vbo.VBO( zeros((1,3)), target=GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER )
    index_vbo = vbo.VBO(index_array, target=GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)
    color_vbo = vbo.VBO(color_array)


    ResizeGLScene( nWidth, nHeight )


def ResizeGLScene( nWidth, nHeight ):
    # prevent a divide-by-zero error if the window is too small
    if nHeight == 0:
        nHeight = 1

    # reset the current viewport and recalculate the perspective transformation
    # for the projection matrix
    glViewport( 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight )
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION )
    glLoadIdentity( )
    gluPerspective( 45.0, float( nWidth )/float( nHeight ), 0.1, 100.0 )

    # return to the modelview matrix mode
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW )

#
# Draw the scene.
#
def DrawGLScene( ):
    # clear the screen and depth buffer
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT )

    # reset the matrix stack with the identity matrix
    glLoadIdentity( )

    global frameno
    frameno = frameno + 1

    glTranslatef( 0.0, -0.2, -2.0 )

    glRotatef( frameno/6, 0.0, sr2, 0.0 )

    # draw code
    #glTranslatef( 0.0, 0.0, -3.0 )
    glScalef( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 )
    glColor3f( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )


    global index_vbo, terrain_vbo, color_vbo

    color_vbo.bind()
    glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY )
    glColorPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, color_vbo )

    terrain_vbo.bind()
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None )

    index_vbo.bind()

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,None)

    glDisableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY )
    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY )

    index_vbo.unbind()
    terrain_vbo.unbind()
    color_vbo.unbind()

    glutSwapBuffers( )

def KeyPressed( key, x, y ):
    key = ord(key)

    if key == 27:
        glutDestroyWindow( hWindow )
        sys.exit( )

def main( ):
    global hWindow

    # initialise GLUT and a few other things
    glutInit( "" )
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH )
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 )
    glutInitWindowPosition( 0, 0 )

    # create our window
    hWindow = glutCreateWindow( "VBO testing" )

    # setup the display function callback
    glutDisplayFunc( DrawGLScene )

    # go full-screen if we want to
    glutFullScreen( )

    # setup the idle function callback -- if we idle, we just want to keep
    # drawing the screen
    glutIdleFunc( DrawGLScene )
    # setup the window resize callback -- this is only needed if we arent going
    # full-screen
    glutReshapeFunc( ResizeGLScene )
    # setup the keyboard function callback to handle key presses
    glutKeyboardFunc( KeyPressed )

    # call our init function
    InitGL( 640, 480 )

    # enter the window's main loop to set things rolling
    glutMainLoop( )


print "Hit ESC key to quit."
main( )
```

Comment: "*without using GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART, which isn't available in GLUT*" That doesn't make sense. GLUT has no effect on the OpenGL implementation, and it's the OpenGL implementation that determines whether primitive restart is available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11259605/2209946 indicates otherwise. I tried the code in the answer on that question and no dice. There are a lot of questions around the web "GLUT won't go past OpenGL 2.1, how fix" and the answer seems to be "switch library".

Comment: Are you on MacOSX? If so, you should say so, because that answer only applies to MacOSX. Furthermore, the answer also only applies to GLUT, not *FreeGLUT*. And nobody should be using GLUT for anything; you should always have been using FreeGLUT.

Comment: Whoops! Forgot to mention the OSX part, thanks. And - well, I am using GLUT, because that's the environment used in my university course. No, it's not ideal. Yes, it's what I've been taught to use, and for a one-semester course I'm going to put up with it.

Comment: GLUT definitely will "go past OpenGL 2.1" on OSX... just pass in GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE to glutInitDisplayMode.