# OpenGL 3.3 on OSX with FreeGLUT

Tags: macos, opengl, freeglut

I am using the following configuration

- Mac OSX v 10.9.1
- Intel HD graphics 4000 1024 MB.

My goal is to use OpenGL 3.3 using FreeGLUT, Is there a way to achieve that?

```
glxinfo gives me:
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Intel HD Graphics 4000 OpenGL Engine
OpenGL version string: 2.1 INTEL-8.18.29
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20, 
and the programs where I try to open a 3.3 context gives me errors.
```

However this site https://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/ states that HD 4000 should support 4.1. Is that only for glsl or is there any way to use FreeGLUT? The reason I want to use freeGlut is because the course I am taking right now requires the assignments to compile on their computers, and they are using FreeGlut, and I would like to be able to work from home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MacOS X supports OpenGL-3.2 and later contexts only if you request a *core* context. You have to initialize FreeGLUT in addition with

```
glutInitContextVersion(3,2); /* or later versions, core was introduced only with 3.2 */
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Another solution is given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751079/524368

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks. Our teachers test program actually initiated the core profile _before_ initializing context 3.2 which for some reason did not work for me.

Comment: *update* It did not work. I tried the solution on the wrong file by mistake, my bad. Following the solution in the link you provided did not even compile as "GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE" is an undeclared identifier. Thank you anyway.