# PyOpenGL OpenGL Version on MacOs

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, shader, pyopengl

I've been told to switch legacy profile to core profile from other stackoverflow posts but I can't seem to find a way to do that. So I'm positing a more updated error post to help me figure out a way.

CODE:

```
import glfw, numpy
from OpenGL.GL import *
import OpenGL.GL.shaders


def main():
    if not glfw.init():
        return

    window = glfw.create_window(800,600,"My OpenGL Window", None, None)

    if not window:
        glfw.terminate()
        return

    glfw.make_context_current(window)

    triangle = [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.5, 0.0]

    triangle = numpy.array(triangle, dtype = numpy.float32)

    vertex_shader = """
    #version 460
    in vec3 position;

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = position;
    }

    """

    fragment_shader = """
    #version 460
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    }
    """

    shader = OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileProgram(OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(vertex_shader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                                              OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(fragment_shader,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))

    VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36, triangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    position = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "position")
    glVertexAttribPoint(position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(position)

    glUseProgram(shader)



    glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 1.0)
    while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
        glfw.poll_events()

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)

        glfw.swap_buffers(window)

    glfw.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I keep getting this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "/Users/Datboi/Desktop/Python/Opengl/main.py", line 71, in <module>
>     main()
> File "/Users/Datboi/Desktop/Python/Opengl/main.py", line 43, in main
>     shader = OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileProgram(OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(vertex_shader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/shaders.py", line 226, in compileShader
>     shaderType,
> RuntimeError: ('Shader compile failure (0): b"ERROR: 0:2: \'\' :  version \'460\' is not supported\\n"', [b'\n    #version 460\n    in vec3 position;\n    \n    void main()\n    {\n        gl_Position = position;\n    }\n\n    '], GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
> ```

I can't seem to find anything to fix this issue. I'm new to OpenGL/PyOpenGL and couldn't find any posts that have asked roughly the same question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ERROR: 0:2: \'\' :  version \'460\' is not supported

is caused because you don't specify the OpenGL version before you create the window. Since your system only support OpenGL verison 4.1, you have to add the follwong lines of code. See  also [OpenGL Development on OS X](https://gist.github.com/v3n/27e810ac744b076ceeb7):

```
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
window = glfw.create_window(800,600,"My OpenGL Window", None, None)
```

If you solve that issue, then you'll face the next issue:

While [`gl_Position`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_Position.xhtml) is a [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates), the vertex shader input variable `position` is of type `vec3`.

The assignment of `gl_Position = position` causes the ERROR:

> assignment of incompatible types

You can solve this issue by changing the vertex shader. Either change the assignment

```
#version 410 core
in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

**or** change the type of the input variable:

```
#version 410 core
in vec4 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

Since `gl_FragColor` is deprecated in core version 4.60, you have to declare a fragment shader output variable instead of using the deprecated built in output variable `gl_FragColor`:

```
 #version 410 core

 out vec4 frag_color; 

 void main()
 {
    frag_color = vec4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
 }
```

Further there is a typo in your program. It has to be [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) instead of `glVertexAttribPoint`.

Note, in a core profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context), you have to use a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object), because the default vertex array object *0* is not valid in a core profile.

> ok im getting this error now
>
> > kages/OpenGL/GL/shaders.py", line 108, in check_validate glGetProgramInfoLog( self ), RuntimeError: Validation failure (0): b'Validation Failed: No vertex array object bound.\n'

Create and bind vertex array object after the OpenGL context has become current:

```
glfw.make_context_current(window)

VAO = glGenVertexArrays(1)
glBindVertexArray(VAO)

shader = OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileProgram(OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(vertex_shader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                                          OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(fragment_shader,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, nothing more recent than OpenGL 4.1 has ever been available on MacOS.  And probably never will be as OpenGL itself is being deprecated on that OS.

Comment: So what can i do?

Comment: @AhmedMerabet Why can't you use OpenGL 4.1?

Comment: because I dont know how to use opengl 4.1 im new to this

Comment: ok im getting this error now kages/OpenGL/GL/shaders.py", line 108, in check_validate
    glGetProgramInfoLog( self ),
RuntimeError: Validation failure (0): b'Validation Failed: No vertex array object bound.\n'

Comment: WOAH IT WORKS TYSM OMFG

Comment: ahahaha. Is there a way I can contact you if i have another problem? You seem to be the only one who understands this.

Comment: @AhmedMerabet The way to solve issues like this is to ask questions on stack overflow. I know some more people here who are experts at this kind of issues. The important thing is to tag the question *opengl*. See the [OpenGL top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opengl/topusers).